# Cannot display images in BitmapField in Blackberry application using simulator 9700?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, runtime-error

I am getting Error while displaying bitmap file in my application.
code:

```
Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/icon.png");
BitmapField bitmapField1 = new BitmapField(logoBitmap, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
add(bitmapField1);
```

Getting error in console tab.
Error: Fridg:couldnot find res/icon.png.

I am using Eclipse with Blackberry Simulator 9700.
I have added the folder and images and it is displaying in the tree of Eclipse.

Comment: Try this: `Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png")`

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to remove "res/" from source string, because it uses res as a source folder.

Comment: +1 Agree with this. Need to write only `Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png")`